# Conditional addition of different values to an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements, addition

I want to add 10 if `x < 50`, 20 if `50 <= x < 100`, 30 if `100 <= x < 150`, and 40 for `150 <= x < 200`. How can I solve this problem? In my array `arr` I have more than 300 data element. Thanks in advance for your kind co-operation.

```
arr =[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200]
```

Comment: I want to add 10 for x<50, 20 for 50<x<100, 30 for 100<x<150, 40 for 150<x<200. How can I solve this problem. In my array (x) I have more than 300 data element. Thanks in advance for your kind co-operation.

Comment: this is not a very difficult question to answer so I would encourage you to look at python `map` or `list comprehension`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a little bit like a homework exercise?
I'd explicitly split out the modifications you need to make so it's easy to see what it's doing. Please note: I did not input ALL your rules, just some, so you can see how you could extend it.

```
x=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200]
for value in x:
     oldvalue = value
     if value  < 50:
         value += 10
     elif value < 100:
         value += 20
     else:
         value += 30
     print("%i => %i" % (oldvalue, value))
```

this prints:

```
10 => 20
20 => 30
30 => 40
40 => 50
50 => 70
60 => 80
70 => 90
80 => 100
....
```

Comment: Thanks. What can I do for two condition at a time like if x<10 & 50<y<100, x+10,y+5? How can I solve by this code? Thanks for your kind co-operation @MichielB

Comment: just change your conditions to include the new statements:

    if value > 10 and value < 50:
        [do something here]

Comment: for xc_141 in x_141:
    oldvaluex = xc_141
    for yc_141 in y_141:
        oldvaluey = yc_141
        if [xc_141<10000] and [yc_141<30000]:
            xc_141 -= 43             
            yc_141+=50
        elif xc_141 < 10000 and 30000<yc_141<46000:
            xc_141 += 212
            yc_141+=50
        else:
           yc_141=y_141-50
           xc_141=x_141-67
        #print ("y value= ", "%d => %d" % (oldvaluey, yc_141))
    else:
        yc_141=y_141-50
        xc_141=x_141-67 
    print ("%d => %d" % (oldvaluex, xc_141))
    plt.plot(xc_141,yc_141,"gs"),

Comment: as you can see these two loop make the problem. I cannot solve it. Thanks again for your kind help.@MichielB

Comment: `for xc_141 in x_141:
    oldvaluex = xc_141
   for yc_141 in y_141:
        oldvaluey = yc_141
        if [xc_141<10000] and [yc_141<30000]:
            xc_141 -= 43             
            yc_141+=50
        elif xc_141 < 10000 and 30000<yc_141<46000:
            xc_141 += 212
            yc_141+=50
        else:
           yc_141=y_141-50
           xc_141=x_141-67
        #print ("y value= ", "%d => %d" % (oldvaluey, yc_141))
    else:
        yc_141=y_141-50
        xc_141=x_141-67 
    #print ("%d => %d" % (oldvaluex, xc_141))
    plt.plot(xc_141,yc_141,"gs")`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy also using panda. Thanks to the guys for the help from this site.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np 
 import pandas as pd
 import math
 import xlwt
 import xlrd


 df_180 = pd.read_csv('Image_146.pft', error_bad_lines=False,header=19)
 df_181 = pd.read_csv('Image_T181.pft', error_bad_lines=False,header=20)

 df_182 = pd.read_csv('Image_T182.pft', error_bad_lines=False, header=20)
 df_183 = pd.read_csv('Image_T183.pft', error_bad_lines=False, header=20)


 x_180=df_180.iloc[:,7]
 y_180=df_180.iloc[:,8]

 x_181=df_181.iloc[:,7]
 y_181=df_181.iloc[:,8]

 x_182=df_182.iloc[:,7]
 y_182=df_182.iloc[:,8]

 x_183=df_183.iloc[:,7]
 y_183=df_183.iloc[:,8]

 plt.style.use('ggplot')

fn ="C:\Users\M15-1478\Desktop\python\Scatter plot.xlsx"
sheetname = 'T181'
df = pd.read_excel(fn, sheetname=sheetname, skiprows=47,    parse_cols='B:C').dropna(how='any')
df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvX <= 500'), 'GrvX'] -= 161
df.ix[df.eval('500 < GrvX <= 1000'), 'GrvX'] -= 114
df.ix[df.eval('1000 < GrvX < 1500'), 'GrvX'] -= 75
df.ix[df.eval('1500 < GrvX < 2000'), 'GrvX'] -= 15
df.ix[df.eval('2000 < GrvX < 2600'), 'GrvX'] += 30
df.ix[df.eval('2600 < GrvX < 2900'), 'GrvX'] += 70

# customize Y-values
df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvY <= 1000'), 'GrvY'] += 30

df.plot(x='GrvX', y='GrvY',  linestyle='no line', marker="o", label=sheetname)
plt.plot(x,y,"gs")

plt.xlabel("x (micron)", size ="18",color ="m")
plt.ylabel("y (micron)", size ="18",color ="m")
plt.title("scatter plot after matching", size ="18",color ="m")
plt.show()
```